# Принцип открытости/закрытости при динамическом определении типа файла

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, инспекция-кода, solid

Есть код приложения в котором необходимо динамически определить тип файла (HTML или TXT) по содержимому и в зависимости от полученного типа файла вызвать соответствующий алгоритм обработки.

```
interface IFileType
{
    void Process();
}
class HtmlFile : IFileType
{
    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HTML");
    }
}
class TxtFile : IFileType
{
    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TXT");
    }
}
class FileTypeHandler
{
    public static IFileType Define(string fileContent)
    {
        var file = fileContent.IndexOf("<html");
        if (file != -1)
        {
            return new HtmlFile();
        }
        else
        {
            return new TxtFile();
        }
    }
}
class FileProcessor
{
    public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
        string fileContent = fileStream.ReadToEnd();
        fileStream.Close();
        var fileType = FileTypeHandler.Define(fileContent);
        fileType.Process();            
    }
}   

class Program
{              
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileProcessor fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
        fileProcessor.ProcessFile(@"d:\index.html");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> HTML

Все работает как мне надо. Меня интересует **насколько гибок мой код к появлению в будущем новых типов файлов**, к примеру JSON. Ведь с появлением нового класса реализующего интерфейс `IFileType`, также **изменится алгоритм определения типа по содержимому** в классе `FileTypeHandler`.

Все ли я правильно спроектировал, касательно принципа открытости/закрытости?

Comment: Можно в интерфейс добавить метод, который будет проверять, его ли формат файла.

Comment: меня больше смущает как вы определяете HTML, остальное вроде нормально выглядит. Как ваш метод определения сработает для текста: "Открывающий и закрывающий теги <html> в документе необязательны, но ....", мне кажется что неправильно. Ну и собственно прямо из цитаты, а если этих тегов нет, но файл таки является HTML-документом?

Comment: @rdorn, я с тобой согласен - код определения формата не ахти). Этот алгоритм будет постоянно меняться. Главное чтобы его изменения не вынуждали менять код в методе `ProcessFile()` класса `FileProcessor`.

Comment: @adamshakhabov да по логике вроде больше ничего не нужно. При сомнениях в правильности определения формата - отдавать его в plain text, и raw binary, если однозначно не распознается даже plain text.

Comment: Я бы сделал Dictionary из действий вместо if. var dict = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
dict.Add(1, () => doCatThing()); 
dict.Add(0, () => doDogThing());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу следующие проблемы в вашем коде.

Метод `FileTypeHandler` содержит логику определения, для **всех** форматов. На данном этапе это не страшно, т.к. их не много, но если их количество будет увеличиваться, метод станет запутанный и тяжел в расширении.

Рекомендую, создать сущности, для каждого формата, и в них реализовывать определение. Это позволит избежать запутанности и облегчит добавление новых.

Приведу код, как я бы в данной ситуации реализовал. В нем есть небольшие упрощения. Написал, на java, но думаю вы разберетесь.

```
enum FormatTypes {
    TXT("txt", new TxtDetector()),
    HTML("html", new HtmlDetector());

    public final String name;
    private final Detector detector;

    FormatTypes(String name, Detector detector) {
        this.name = name;
        this.detector = detector;
    }
}

interface Detector {
    boolean isCorrectType(String fileName, String content);
}

class TxtDetector implements Detector {
}

class HtmlDetector implements Detector {
}

class DetectorHandler {
    public static String getType(String fileName) {
        String content = //чтение содержимого

        for (FormatTypes types : FormatTypes.values())
            if (types.detector.isCorrectType(fileName, content))
                //просто возвращает название формата, 
                //можно при необходимости в FormatTypes положить какую то логику
                return types.name;

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("type is not supported");
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, определение типа файла в общем случае так просто не декомпозируется.

Comment: Кстати, если вы пишите на Java - зачем вам вообще дополнительные классы? Всю логику можно было в FormatTypes уместить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, декомпозиция определения типа сложна. В этом и заключалась основная сложность проектирования в этом коде. Но тем не менее, Artem не плохой вариант предложил.

Comment: @PavelMayorov дополнительные классы это вы про классы реализующие Detector? Можно конечно, логику определения формата запихать в енум, но через отдельные классы на мой взгляд решение более расширяемое получается и выглядит это лучше.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не понял, почему определение класса просто так не декомпозируется? чем плох мой вариант? каждый Detector содержит свою  логику, она не зависит от других. чем это не декомпозиция?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а теперь в своей структуре закодируйте правила для форматов jsp, aspx, cshtml и php. Напомню, что каждый из них может содержать тэг `<html>` - но это не сделает его html-документом.

Comment: эмм. тут вопрос уже в однозначном определение формата, а не в структуре классов. Если реализованный алгоритм делает какие то допущения то проблема уже в нем.